# Generation of random Image by tapping on imageView

Tags: java, android, random

I simply want to generate a random image from drawable images, when i tap on the imageView. Whenever i run this code, the app on the emulator gets crashed. what's wrong with this code:

```
package com.example.surya.musicpleer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView i1;
Random r = new Random();
int target = r.nextInt(3);
String drawablename = "photo" + target;

int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(drawablename, "drawable",  getPackageName());

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    i1 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i1.setImageResource(resID);
        }
    });
        }
```

}

Comment: What's the crash's stack trace?

Comment: asked bazillion times, your call of `getResources()` is premature .... context is not ready yet

Comment: what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Post the logcat error here

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Modified your code just copy & paste it, your problem was you are creating random no & accessing resource out of `onCreate()` method

```
 package com.example.surya.musicpleer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView i1;
    Random r = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int target = r.nextInt(3);
                String drawablename = "photo" + target;

                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(drawablename, "drawable", getPackageName());

                i1.setImageResource(resID);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You need to put four images in drawable like photo0 to photo3

**EDIT**

Unfortunately there is notany method to get drawable of imageview but you can do it by `setTag()` to imageview as below

```
i1.setImageResource(resID);
i1.setTag(resID); // this line is importent
```

& get that tag using this method

```
private int getDrawableId(ImageView iv) {
    return (Integer) iv.getTag();
}
```

now u can compare values returned by above method if they are same means both imageview have same drawable.

Comment: thanks a lot.. and now i am gonna do it for another imageView also but i want to do if both the images are same then i need to get a popup like you won